# Nginx sub dir rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am facing Nginx rewrite rule issue while trying to beautify some urls e.g

```
http://subdomain.mywebsite.com:1234/someuser/temp/min/?g=home&v=049075caf8fc8193892c286889040861a8148de3
```

where,

```
g = <some js file> and 
v = <version of file>
```

to something like,

```
http://subdomain.mywebsite.com:1234/someuser/temp/min/049075caf8fc8193892c286889040861a8148de3/home.js
```

My virtual host file (subdomain.mywebsite.com inside /etc/nginx/sites-available) is having entry as,

```
rewrite ^/someuser/temp/min/([^/]*)/home.js$ /someuser/temp/min/?g=home&v=$1 last;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rewrite rule to get `/049075caf8fc8193892c286889040861a8148de3/home.js` as if you used `/?g=home&v=049075caf8fc8193892c286889040861a8148de3`

```
rewrite ^/someuser/temp/min/(.*)/(.*\.js)$ /someuser/temp/min/?g=$2&v=$1 last;
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working. Is there any particular thing about port 1234?

Comment: hmm, could be the port thing. can you test if it works when you run it on port 80?

Comment: Ok finally I got this thing working. @jagsier thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
rewrite ^/someuser/temp/min/([^/]+)/(.*).js$ /someuser/temp/min/?g=$2&v=$1 last;
```